# Aptana Studio - Is it possible to add TODO tags in Javascript files?

Tags: javascript, php, aptana

I am working on a PHP project in Aptana Studio. I have recently noticed the `// TODO` tag feature, meaning that Aptana notices them and keeps them in a list for me. This is great, only thing is, it seems to only work in PHP files, e.g. in index.php I have the following:

`// TODO sanitise input`

which results in a little todo icon in the margin and then it appears in the todo list below.

Results in the task icon and then the task list looks like this

[image: TODO list]

If I do the same thing in a Javascript file, however, it is not added to the list. Anyone know how to change the settings so that it does the same thing for jscript?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What is the version your are using?

Comment: "Aptana Studio 3, build: 3.6.1.201410201044"